# Hide server-side technology information from the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, web-applications, browser

I have installed Wappalyzer add-on installed for Firefox browser. When I access my web application, it displays server-side technologies used. In this case it displays following information:

- Node.js (Programming language)
- Express (Web framework)
- Connect (Web framework)

I need to somehow hide these information from the browser/client for security purpose. So, could anyone shed some light on how I do this in node.js. Is there any configuration settings that I can change so that they won't send unnecessary information to the browser/client.

**Update:**

I used following code to prevent Express framework from sending 'x-powered-by' header:

```
app.disable('x-powered-by');
```

Even after this change, the server side stack information is being displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you print the header(s) you are complaining about? I am not sure which server side information specifically is exposed.

Comment: The information exposed are the ones I've mentioned in the list above. The response header had **x-powered-by** set to *Express*; which, I thought was used by the Wappalyzer to determine the server side information (like, programming language used & node.js framework used). Now, even after removing the x-powered-by header, the Wappalyzer is able identify the server side stack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally its working. The **app.disable('x-powered-by')** did the trick. After clearing the cache Wappalyzer was not able to determine the server-side stack information.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can i used this in codeigniter and cakephp?

Answer (score 3):

For those with no custom server, add the following to next.config.js:

```
poweredByHeader: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from server side technology by PHP frameworks, change

```
expose_php = off
```

in your php.ini.